# How do I evaluate the angular momentum of the wave function?

Tags: condensed-matter, angular-momentum, simulations, bose-einstein-condensate

I'm working with Bose-Einstein condensates and running a 2D single component Gross-Pitaevskii equation solver for the simulations in MATLAB.

The way it works is that it numerically solves the GP equation and the end result leaves me with the ground state wave function of the BEC in the harmonic trap, after which I do real time evaluation of the GP equation. (Let me know if I should add more details to how the code works)

I need to evaluate the angular momentum of the wave function now and prove that it remains constant/unchanged during the real time evaluation.

What I have -

- the groundstate wave function as a matrix

What I need -

- evaluate $\langle \hat{L} \rangle$ = $\langle \psi \mid \hat{L} \mid \psi \rangle $

My question -

1. Where do I get the $\hat{L}$ from?
2. Do I evaluate the bra-ket vectors in MATLAB? Or, do I solve $\int_{\mathbf{R^3}}\Psi^{*}\hat{L}\Psi \,\mathbf{dr}^3$ using numerical integration in MATLAB?

I have spent an entire week thinking about it and it is seemingly simple but I just can't wrap my head around it. Please help!

Comment: Is $\hat{L}$ not the normal angular momentum operator in QM?

Answer (score 1):

1. Angular momentum operator in quantum mechanics is defined as:
   $$\hat{L}=-i\hbar[r\times\nabla]$$
   You just need to insert this definition of $\hat{L}$ to $\langle \psi|\hat{L}|\psi\rangle$ (or integral) to calculate.
2. You need to use the integral form for the average of $\hat{L}$ and use numerical methods to evaluate.

Also, angular momentum is not of the wave function, but of particles. $\langle L\rangle=\langle \psi|\hat{L}|\psi\rangle$ is the average of $\hat{L}$ of particle in state $|\psi\rangle$.